# django-auditlog: traversing relationships to get LogEntries of related objects

Tags: django, django-auditlog

For tracking changes, I've created a mixin to add auditlog to model components to make tracking change uniform. It's paying dividends when it's time to generate reports about what's changed.

```
class ChangeMixin:
    history = AuditlogHistoryField()

    def get_all_changes(self, range_start=DAY_START, range_end=DAY_END):
        """
        returns all the changes on this instance within a defined time period.  The default period is today.

        :type range_end: datetime
        :type range_start: datetime
        """
        result = []

        if range_start > range_end:
            return result

        if self.history is None:
            return result

        result = LogEntry.objects.get_for_object(self).filter(timestamp__range=(range_start, range_end))

        return result
```

However, there's a fly in the ointment that this solution doesn't address: how to get the corresponding bits from related objects.  That is, if there is a one to many or a many to many relationship, how do pursue the relationship to get the target data?

For example, if there's a one to many relationship, say `Book` to `Genre`, the LogEntry stores the id of the `Genre` in the change record and the hope is get the text version of the record whose id is in the LogEntry.  That is, the genre for a book, say the Hobbit, might get changed from `fiction` to `fantasy`.  The `LogEntry` record for the `Hobbit` might show this as `'genre': ['1', '2']` where 1 and 2 are ids.  And what is wanted for the presentation would be the print version of the records from the genre table, e.g. `Genre.objects.get(id=1).print_me_out_as_readable_text()`, or something like this.

I don't see how I can adjust the mixin to achieve this.

Harder is a relationship where objects on both sides change. So for example suppose there's an object with two fields that points at another object that has one field.  There I'm trying to do something like:

```
Object 1
    field 1: a => b
    field 2: c => d
    Object 2
        field a: 1 => 2...
```

In the LogEntry record, I see something like

```
'answers': ['None', 'RelatedManager (PolymorphicManager) using PolymorphicQuerySet']
```

where `object 1` has a field `answers` that points toward an `answer` object.

The documentation gives the following example (for m2m relationships):

```
obj = MyModel.objects.first()
rel_history = LogEntry.objects.get_for_objects(obj.related.all())
full_history = (obj.history.all() | rel_history.all()).order_by('-timestamp')
```

What I don't understand is how one can integrate this snippet into the mixin to handle every relationship field so to maintain a capability that doesn't have to be adjusted for each relationship or change in relationship.  That is, how do you adjust `obj.related.all()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a direct way.  How I solved this was to add field which is a list of object names to pursue and then added a method to each class for getting the related `auditlog.LogEntry` instances.  These don't come easily via querying for `LogEntry` records.

For example, a `Student` might have a related object `Intake` that has it's own `auditlog` instances:

```
class Student(Model, ChangeMixin):
    ...lots of stuff...
    intake = models.OneToOneField(Intake, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False
    # intake generated a separate LogEntry on changes

    pursuit_fields = ['intake']
```

I created ChangeMixin to standardize (somewhat) getting the LogEntry instances.  It adds a method to the class to retrieve all the `auditlog` entries.  In my case, it always involved a date range.  The pursue parameter is whether or not to get related `auditlog` entries.  The result is a dict where a key is a "cleaned-up" version of the instance's name and the value is the set of `LogEntry`.

```
class ChangeMixin:
    history = AuditlogHistoryField(). # straight from the documentation

    def get_all_changes(self, range_start=DAY_START, range_end=DAY_END, pursue=True):
        """
        returns all the changes on this instance within a defined time period.  The default period is today.

        :param pursue: bool    whether to collect related object histories
        :type range_end: datetime
        :type range_start: datetime
        """
        result = dict()

        if range_start > range_end:
            return result

        if self.history is None:
            return result

        # this gets the auditlog entries for this instance, again straight from the docs
        main_set = LogEntry.objects.get_for_object(self).filter(timestamp__range=(range_start,
                                                                                  range_end))
        if main_set.count() != 0:
            result[clean_up_names(self._meta.model_name)] = main_set

        # now to chase the related object auditlogs
        if pursue:
            for pursuit in self.pursuit_fields:
                the_objects = getattr(self, pursuit)
                # hack time - for the one to many side of some relationships, I can't seem to figure out how to get them
                # programmatically.  So I just dealt with them as one-of's.  Not ideal, but...
                if pursuit in ['goals', 'goal_comment', 'answers']:
                    the_object = getattr(self, pursuit).all()
                    change_set = LogEntry.objects.get_for_objects(the_object).filter(timestamp__range=(range_start,
                                                                                                       range_end))
                else:
                    change_set = LogEntry.objects.get_for_object(getattr(self,
                                                                         pursuit)).filter(timestamp__range=(range_start,
                                                                                                            range_end))
                
                if change_set.count() != 0:
                    result[clean_up_names(pursuit)] = change_set

        return result
```